# How to programmatically simulate XP's "Windows Security" start menu option on Windows 2000

Tags: windows, security, rdp

I'm trying to find a way to invoke the Ctrl+Alt+Delete dialog on a Windows 2000 computer that I'm connected to via Remote Desktop. Windows XP and 2003 include a new start menu command called "Windows Security" that does this, but Windows 2000 has no such option.

It appears that Ctrl+Alt+End will do this, but it only goes to the outermost RDP window, so if you're several connections deep, it doesn't help. In this scenario, I'm on computer A, connected to computer B. From computer B, I connect to computer C. Pressing Ctrl+Alt+End opens the Ctrl+Alt+Delete dialog on computer B, not computer C.

The goal here is to allow users connecting to computer C to change their own passwords. The users are not administrators on the computer, so they can't access the various tools that an admin might use to accomplish this.

[edit] I forgot to make this a programming question; my intent was to figure out how to do this from code (although a non-code method would be useful as well).

Comment: You forgot the magic words: "programatically" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My coworker found the way to accomplish this directly: Start | Settings | Windows Security. If it's not present, it may have been disabled via Group Policy ([Technet](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windows2000serv/reskit/gp/1.mspx?mfr=true)).